# Install R in linux/Unix without having root privilage?

Tags: linux, r

I am trying to install R in our cluster(OS of cluster is Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6), where I do not have root access. I tried:

```
$wget http://cran.rstudio.com/src/base/R-3/R-3.1.1.tar.gz
$ tar xvf R-3.1.1.tar.gz
$ cd R-3.1.1
$ ./configure --prefix=/home/Kryo/R-3.1.1
```

But getting error:

> configure: error: --with-x=yes (default) and X11 headers/libs are not available

Comment: Do you have X11 forwarding enabled? Maybe try `./configure --prefix=/home/Kryo/R-3.1.1 --with-x=no`

Comment: @choff, i tried ./configure --prefix=/home/Rajith.Bhaskaran/Tools/R-3.1.1 --without-x

Comment: And you still get the same error? I'm not sure how to proceed then. Maybe try with the option `--with-readline=no` as well. I read elsewhere that you might need `libXt-devel` too.

Comment: @choff, when i tried to run  ./configure --prefix=/home/Kryo/R-3.1.1 --with-x=no. im getting error. But when i tried  ./configure --prefix=/home/Kryo/R-3.1.1 --with-x it worked.  R is now configured for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

  Source directory:          .
  Installation directory:    /home/Kryo/Tools/R-3.1.1.   Now when i  tried R in terminal im getting -bash: R: command not found.

Comment: You still need to install it. In the R-3.1.1 directory type `make` and then `make install`. Then you will need to add `R` to your path to be able to start it from the command line.

Comment: @choff, how should i add R to my path. I know its a trivial question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83139/discussion-between-kryo-and-choff).

Comment: Check the chat, I answered your question there.

Comment: You can install it from conda (no root privilege is required, this is how I do it on our servers). By doing so, you can also keep multiple installations of r-base in different environments.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative is to install r-base from conda. One does not need the root privilege for doing it. The root privilege is not needed for installing anaconda/miniconda, neither.

 Installing r-base through conda:

```
conda install -c r r-base
```

Once R is installed, you can install R packages as usual and conda will detect them and list them on the environment. 

One disadvantage of installing R from conda is that the R version available at conda might not always be the latest version of R.

Link to the corresponding conda package: https://anaconda.org/r/r-base

Comment: Didn't work for me: `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:`

Comment: You can try installing it from another channel.
Here is a list of channels for `r-base` https://anaconda.org/search?q=r-base