# How to install R on a linux cluster?

Tags: r, linux, installation

I use a cluster (OS is Linux) which does not have R. I would like to install `R` in my personal folders so that I can just do

```
Rscript example.R arg1 arg2
```

How should I install R on this cluster knowing that I don't have admin rights?

How can I then manage the packages?

Comment: The best solution is to ask your administrator to install it or to give you temporary permissions to install it. Having said that there are portable versions of R that won't require you to have `sudo` privileges and of course you could always have a VM. Related: https://sourceforge.net/projects/rportable/files/R-Portable/ Or you could send some phishing emails to the admin and steal his password. Just sayin.

Comment: Thank you. The cluster is specifically anti-R as apparently it takes a lot of maintenance and all users of this cluster have access to another cluster which allows R (but which offers too little storage for my needs). The link you provide seems helpful.

Comment: This is a pretty useless question as there is _nothing_ specific to R here.  You can share _any_ application from your home directory this way.  It is also a duplicate of at least [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388102/install-r-in-linux-unix-without-having-root-privilage) and probably many more.

Comment: If I were your system admin I would block you from using that cluster when I noticed that you are running R on it even though it is not allowed.

Comment: @Roland...oh good point. Can you please elaborate why it could represent any issue for the cluster that I use R?

Comment: depends why it's "not allowed". If it's just "we don't *support* it" (because it's too high-maintenance, although I don't know what that means -- they don't want to install new versions at least once a year?) that doesn't mean they mind if users install it for themselves, as long as they don't ask for help. Bottom line: talk to your sysadmin (your above-stated reason for wanting to use R on this cluster seems reasonable to me ...)

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks I'll follow your advice!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure this is on-topic, but: all you really have to do is

- download the R source tarball from CRAN; unpack it somewhere in your file space
- create an `r-build` directory at the same level of the hierarchy (not technically necessary, but it's better practice to keep the source and build directories separate)
- create an installation directory (say `~/r_install`) somewhere sensible within your file space
- `cd` to the source directory; `tools/rsync-recommended`
- `cd` to the build directory
- `../[srcdir]/configure --prefix=~/r_install`
- `make` (to build the binaries)
- `make install` (to move everything where it belongs; not technically necessary, as you can run R from the build directory)

Where this may get hairy is with all of the system requirements for R (LaTeX, Java, bzip2, etc. etc. ...) it is *theoretically* possible to download all this stuff and install it in your own file space, but it starts to get sufficiently tedious that it will be easier to beg your sysadmin to install at least the dependencies for you ...

as @Hack-R points out [the basics of this answer are already present on Unix & Linux stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149451/install-r-in-my-own-directory), although my answer is a little more detailed ...

Comment: Note that you don't *have* to do the install step. You can run R from the build directory.